# MariaDB truncated datetime value

Tags: mariadb

We have a data table with incorrect data in a date date . Now I get a warning about that and while this is not a bug I like to be able to query for the rows with that wrong column values.

Unfortunately this column is part of the primary key, so the next worry seems to be the removal of that wrong data...

The SQL modes in effect are:
`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Is there a query that translates to show me the rows with warnings? And how to later remove the rows in question?

Comment: *Now I get a warning about that* Speaking about errors and warnings you must provide complete error message text. We cannot predict what type of the incorrectness you deal with. Also provide complete CREATE TABLE script and an example of problematic rows (if possibe in INSERT INTO form, or at least as CLI output of the SELECT with small LIMIT).

Comment: Let's see the value.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  What is preventing the "query for the rows with that wrong column values."?  Do you get an error, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was actually totally misled. Did match on date in the wehre clause wrong and that resulted in a wrong datetime value. So no issue after a co-worker opened my eyes...